# Torment of grave

Tags: grave

As it is said that as the person dies, the torment in his grave starts so the people who have died much earlier then will their torment be much greater than those people who died recently?

Comment: Crom where you heard this? The torment of grave is according to one’s belief and deeds, not by age.

Comment: Your question sounds not to refer much to Islam but more to mathematics, how to count time. No matter who died first, it is from the beginning to the end, and if it is eternity, then there is no difference when it started.

Answer (score 0):

**Praise be to Allah.**

Every soul will taste death. And you will only receive your full reward on the Day of Judgment. Whoever is spared from the Fire and is admitted into Paradise will ˹indeed˺ triumph, whereas the life of this world is no more than the delusion of enjoyment.
**[Surah Al- Imran Verse 185]**

And the record ˹of deeds˺ will be laid ˹open˺, and you will see the wicked in fear of what is ˹written˺ in it. They will cry, “Woe to us! What kind of record is this that does not leave any sin, small or large, unlisted?” They will find whatever they did present ˹before them˺. And your Lord will never wrong anyone.**[Surah Al- Kahaf Verse 49]**

**Surah Al- Imran Verse 185** And you will only receive your full reward on the Day of Judgment.

**Surah Al- Kahaf Verse 49** your Lord will never wrong anyone.

It's clear that you will only receive your full reward on the Day of Judgment. your Lord will never wrong anyone

Answer (score 0):

Things about torment of the grave come under the heading

> GHAIB - The things that we cannot be sure of.

There are reasons for that because there plenty of ahadiths which you read from time to time that torment of the grave exists.
Although in Quran Surah Yaseen verse 51-52 it is written

> And the Horn will be blown, and suddenly they will be rushing from their graves towards their Lord. (51)

> They will say, “Woe to us! Who has raised us from our sleeping place? “This is what RaHmān (the All-Merciful Allah) had promised, and the messengers had told the truth.(52)

When we read such things we conclude that we only need to now that we are answerable and thus it will be a way for our forgiveness. Doesn't matters if there is a torment of grave or not because you need to have right deeds to get help from Allah even on the Day Of Judgment.

A very famous Urdu Scholar Dr. Israr had this opinion. You can search it on youtube.
JazakAllah